# Data recovery bitolockerd partition

Tags: recovery

I have toshiba laptop firstly my pc has 3 partitions. one partition has been locked by bitlocker.

when I tried to format my pc it shows you can not install in this GPT partition you must change to MBR. to solve that I change the partition type from GPT to MBR using cmd. at that time all the partitions came to single large partition. I finished the installation process with one partition only.

to recover my data I tried to use icare data recovery tool.I can recover one partition with entire data inside it.I cannot get the second bitlockered partition.I could not remember the exact size...

I tried many times still not exist that partition....

please help me...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you had an encrypted partition which you've formatted by changing partition type. Recovery tools attempt read your data from disk and guess while types and boundaries, with encrypted data that's not possible, so there is very low to zero chance that data could be recovered.

Comment: I can get get all contents of one partition.why for the other with bitlockered....

Comment: Bitlocker encrypts your data to prevent non-authorised access, if circumventing that would be as easy as formatting your storage then that technology wouldn't have been used. Again, the answer is: NO.

Comment: **Your actions have made data recovery impossible.**  You should have came to us when you were attempting to install Windows, we would have helped you solved that problem, and you wouldn't have loss your data.

Answer (score 2):

You had an encrypted partition which you've formatted by changing partition type.

Recovery tools attempt to read your data from disk and guess file types and boundaries, with encrypted data that's not possible, so there is very low to zero chance that data could be recovered.